# 指令統制スキーム以外のソフトウェアアーキテクチャ

Tags: c

> 現世代のソフトウェア アーキテクチャでは、ほとんどのプログラムはあるメソッドが別のメソッドを呼び出して、何らかのアクションの実行を指示する指令統制(command and control)スキームによって構築されている。
>   GAMW PROGRAMMING Gems 8 日本語版,P.388,4.6.4コールスタックの生成

と書いてありました。
**ほとんど**ということは、それ以外のものもあるということですよね。
どのようなものがあるのですか？

Comment: 「ほとんどのプログラムは指令統制スキームによって構築されているようですが、」と書かれておられますが、「指令統制スキーム」とはどの文献から言葉を取り出したものでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。英語版ではP405でした。別に日本語版の訳がおかしいというわけでもなさそうです。コールスタックを使わないプログラム(できれば実用的なもの？)が提示できれば回答としては良さそうですかね。

Comment: すみませんでした。日本語版です。以後気をつけます。コメントに記載していた書籍に関する情報を編集し記載しコメントを削除しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

該当の箇所は原文では、以下のように書かれていました。

> ### Call-stack Generation
>
> In the current generation of software architecture, most programs are
>   built on a command and control scheme: One method calls another method
>   and instructs it to perform some action. The place that stores the
>   nested method call information is the call stack. From a low-...
>
> (Adam Lake, Game Programming Gems 8, P.405)

ソフトウェア・アーキテクチャのことであれば、この部分で対比して語られているのは、イベント駆動型のプログラミング（メッセージ駆動型、メッセージ思考とかそのたぐい）だと思います。プログラムが走るハードウェア・スレッドが同じだとすれば、主な違いは、「呼び出し元」と「呼び出される側」の区別が付きにくくなることでしょうか？ （自分は納得いかないので、詳しい解説は他の人の回答で？）

Comment: 情報が間違っていてすみませんでした。

Comment: 質問が十分な内容になりましたから、この質問は全く問題ないですよ。サイトの趣旨に沿ってます！

Comment: FYI: [Programming without a Call Stack - Event-driven Architectures](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/docs/hohpe_event_driven_architectures.pdf)という資料がありました。@HiroshiYamamotoさんが指摘するように、ここでは暗にコールスタックによるトップダウン型と、イベント駆動によるボトムアップ型のソフトウェア・アーキテクチャの対比があるようにも思えます。